# How to merge with rebase?

Tags: git

```
git checkout featurebranch
git rebase develop
git checkout develop
git merge featurebranch
```

Does git have a built in command / switch to achieve the same?

Comment: you could always make a git alias for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a shorter sequence for this,

```
git rebase develop featurebranch
git checkout -B develop
```

because the merge is a fast forward, just re-hanging the label, which the checkout -B does.

Comment: ... unless the user has configured merge to be `--no-ff`, that is. :-) But this is probably what the OP would like.

Comment: if develop has commits A,B,C and featurebranch has A,B,D wouldn't this sequence create A,B,D,C where the original would create A,B,C,D ?

Comment: Nope.  The rebase here does exactly exactly what your first two commands do; the second does exactly (unless you've shut off default fast-forwards) what your second two commands do.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no: Git does not have a "rebase other branch, then merge it" command.  You can write a script to do it, but you will have to decide how the script should behave if the rebase stops with a conflict.  Note that `git rebase` has a well-defined exit status: zero means "finished successfully", nonzero means "stopped with merge conflict, or failed entirely".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a shell on Linux, here are a couple things you could do.

Use `&&` to move on to the next command if the previous one is successful:

```
git checkout featurebranch && git rebase develop && git checkout develop && git merge featurebranch
```

If you don't want to type that each time and you're working with the same branch each time, you could set an alias in your `~/.bashrc`. Just add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file (note: you can change `mergeRebaseBranchName` to whatever you want):

```
alias mergeRebaseBranchName='git checkout featurebranch && git rebase develop && git checkout develop && git merge featurebranch'
```

An alias is sort of like creating a custom command. So now when you type `mergeRebaseBranchName` in the terminal it will run the commands for you.

Comment: These sure are options but this is basically a cop out. Edited my question to make it more clear. Sigh.

Comment: Yeah, your questions was too broad. Now that you have edited your question to ask if `git` specifically has a builtin command, you could try looking up git aliases. Although, that is more complicated through `git` if you're trying to pack multiple commands into one alias.